# Confused about If statement

Tags: conditional

I have this simple test code:

```
n1 = 0;
n2 = 0;
m = 0;
If[n1 == 0, n2 == 1]
```

which evaluates as False, as it should. However, if I do:

```
If[n1 == 0, n2 == 1; m = 1];
m
```

I get 1 instead of 0 (m value shouldn't change, if the expression evaluates to False). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Translation to make it easier to see. When you write

```
 If[n1 == 0, n2 == 1]
```

This translates to

```
IF n1==0 THEN
   n2==1 (*this gives False*)
END IF
```

Since last expression of `IF` is its value, then the above returns `False` which is what you got.

Now when you write

```
 If[n1 == 0,  n2 == 1;  m = 1  ];
```

This translates to

```
 IF  n1 == 0 THEN
     n2==1; (*this does nothing, it just gives False, but not used*)
     m=1 (*this assigned  m =1, over writing its old value of zero*)
 END IF
```

The last expression gives `1` now, which is value of `m` after it was assigned.

Now when you check you find `m` is `1` as expected.

> m value shouldn't change

Why? You assigned `1` to `m`, so it should change? Mathematica is correct.

> what I want to do is, if n1=0 and n2=1 them m=1. I tried using && and
> "and" instead of the come between n1=0 , n2=1, but they didn't work
> either

It seems you thought that `n1==0 , n2==1` means `n1==0` *and* `n2==1` but that is not the case. It translates to `n1==0 THEN n2==1`. The *first* comma inside the `If` means `THEN` and not logical and and the *second* comma means `ELSE`.

So to do what you want use

```
 If[n1 == 0 && n2 == 1, m = 1]
```

Now `m` stays zero

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above can also be written as

```
 If[And[n1==0,n2==1],m=1]
```

Which translates to

```
 IF  n1==0 AND n2==1 THEN
     m=1
 END IF
```

### Appendix

The structure of `If` is this

```
If[  booleanValuedExpression , truePart, falsePart ]
```

Which translates to

```
IF  booleanValuedExpression THEN
    truePart expressions separated by `;'
ELSE
    falsePart expressions separated by `;' but do not end last one by `;`
END IF
```

So you see that the *first* comma inside `If` translates to `THEN` and the *second* comma translates to `ELSE` and the closing `]` translates to `END IF`.

The above is for the two argument `If`. Mathematica also also has the three arguments `If`.

When writing my complicated if then else in Mathematica, I like to do  alignment as follows to make it clear to me

```
If[  booleanValued  ,

       stuff; 
       stuff;
       more stuff
 ,
       stuff;
       stuff;
       more stuff
 ]
```

I use code cell and not input cell when writing in notebooks (for .m files (i.e package files), I use notepad++ so I am free to do any alignment I want).

Using code cell in notebook makes it easier to do the above.

I always put the `ELSE` (which is the second comma in Mathematica) shifted left to align under the `If` so it is more clear to me reading the code.

I must admit I old fashioned and prefer explicit `THEN, ELSE, END IF` in code instead of commas and braces or spaces (as in Python).  These make the logic more clear to me.

Comment: Ah sorry, what I want to do is, if n1=0 and n2=1 them m=1. I tried using && and "and" instead of the come between n1=0 , n2=1, but they didn't work either

Comment: @Silviu updated.